# Book: Girl can see magical creatures, finds secret passages at her grandparents'

Tags: story-identification, books

I can only remember bits and pieces of the book. A girl finds out she can see magical creatures after going to her grandparents house.  In the middle of the book she finds a journal (or it's her journal) that she buries by a tree. She finds secret passages that lead to different parts of the house. One passage leads to a hidden nursery where I think the grandma hid her daughter.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This question could use additional details; you should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if you can remember any additional details to [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/208321/edit) into your question.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be the *[Fablehaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fablehaven)* series written by Brandon Mull?

> The series begins as 13-year-old Kendra and 11-year-old Seth Sorenson are traveling to their Grandpa and Grandma Sorenson's house while their parents are away on a 17-day cruise. When they get there, they also meet Dale, the groundskeeper, and Lena, the housekeeper. Grandma Sorenson is "mysteriously" missing. Grandpa Sorenson does not tell Kendra and Seth about Fablehaven being a secret preserve for magical creatures at first, but instead sets up a rather complex puzzle involving six keys and a locked journal for Kendra to solve. Once Kendra unlocks the mostly blank journal, she discovers the words "Drink the milk." She and Seth drink the magical milk Dale sets outside in their yard every morning, opening their eyes to a whole new, mystical world full of the magical beings of Fablehaven. Then Kendra and Seth must face challenges such as defeating an evil witch and a powerful demon, defending the preserve from an evil society, stopping a plague that changes creatures of light into creatures of darkness, accidentally turning Lena into a naiad, and, ultimately, protecting the world from a horde of imprisoned demons.

I had previously suggested this book as an answer to [Series where a girl joins a magic creature guarding society](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182428/series-where-a-girl-joins-a-magic-creature-guarding-society/182446#182446).

Comment: If so, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: What does not match (as best I can tell, since I've never actually read the series) is that the grandmother is not hiding a daughter in a nursery (although she is present throughout the first book, albeit transformed).

Comment: I read those, and I don't remember anything about the daughter. IIRC their parents were pretty oblivious to what happened, and furthermore the Sorensons are their father's parents

Comment: It seemed close enough that it was worth posting even if it doesn't match on all counts. :)